# Values for char arrays keep changing

Tags: java, class, object, multidimensional-array, global-variables

I have two different two dimensional arrays for storing a map in the form:

```
 [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
 [#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #]
 [#, ., ., ., ., ., ., G, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., E, ., #]
 [#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #]
 [#, ., ., E, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #]
 [#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., G, ., ., ., ., ., ., #]
 [#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., P, ., ., ., #]
 [#, ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., ., #]
 [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
```

I have this assigned to the variable mapArrayGlobal, however when i call the method createBlankArray() it seems to change this variable. My full code for the class is as follows:

```
 static int Column, Row, goldNumber;
int goldCount = 0;
char [][] mapArrayGlobal, mapBlank;
boolean goldMarker = false;
boolean exitSet = false;

public void setPosition(int rows, int column, char [][] TwoDArray, int goldValue){
    goldNumber = goldValue;
    Column = randInt(1, column - 1);
    Row = randInt(1, rows - 2);

    mapArrayGlobal = TwoDArray;
    mapBlank = mapArrayGlobal;

    if(mapArrayGlobal[Row][Column] == '#'){
        setPosition(rows, column, TwoDArray, goldValue);
    }
    else if(mapArrayGlobal[Row][Column] == 'G'){
        goldMarker = true;
        mapArrayGlobal[Row][Column] = 'P';
    }
    else{
        mapArrayGlobal[Row][Column] = 'P';
    }
    createBlankArray(TwoDArray);
}

public void createBlankArray(char [][] array){
    printArray(array);
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < array[0].length - 1; j++){
            mapBlank[i][j] = '?';
        }   
    }
    printArray(mapBlank);
    printArray(mapArrayGlobal);
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    Random rand = new Random();

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

At the end of this code the value of mapArrayGlobal and mapBlank are both:

```
 [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
 [#, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, #]
 [#, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, #]
 [#, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, #]
 [#, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, #]
 [#, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, #]
 [#, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, #]
 [#, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, #]
 [#, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #, #]
```

Can anybody advise as to why this is.

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 2):

You are in fact passing (the value of) the reference of the `TwoDArray` variable to the `createBlankArray` method. Since you have:

```
mapArrayGlobal = TwoDArray;
mapBlank = mapArrayGlobal;
```

mapBlank points to mapArrayGlobal which points to `TwoDArray` and changing mapBlank therefore results in changing `TwoDArray`'s elements.

As an aside, you shouldn't start variable/instance names with a capital letter. The convention for naming variables is `camelCase`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Yes. The simplest thing that comes to mind is to just have your createBlankArray() method return a "blank" array with the right dimensions - possibly taking the dimensions as an argument.